# mysql.createConnection is not a function when using node.js to connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is the code I have so far:

**index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = app.listen(1019);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(serv);
var mysqli = require("mysqli");
var connection = mysqli.createConnection({
    host: "%",
    user: "*******",
    password: "*******", 
    database: "DragonBattle" 
});
connection.connect();
```

I used `npm install mysqli --save` and installed mysqli 3.0.1

Then when I run `node index.js`, is says:

```
var connection = mysqli.createConnection({
                        ^

TypeError: mysqli.createConnection is not a function
```

I am using the MySQL server that came with XAMPP

Comment: if you would like to use mysqli you should follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysqli , if you would like to use createConnection you should follow https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: If I use `mysqli` according to that website it says `Mysqli is not defined`. If I use `mysql.createConnection` it says `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND % % 3306 `

Comment: because it is really undefined, you must first do `var Mysqli = require('mysqli')`

Comment: thx, do you have information on how to do `mysqli_query`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and that kind of stuff using node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to follow the documentation from the package that you are using, not any documentation from another package. Here's an excerpt from your package's documentation for creating a connection

```
let conn = new Mysqli({
  host: '', // IP/域名
  post: 3306, //端口， 默认 3306
  user: '', //用户名
  passwd: '', //密码
  charset: '', // 数据库编码，默认 utf8 【可选】
  db: '' // 可指定数据库，也可以不指定 【可选】
})
```

There's another package though, one that is more widely used in nodejs. It's found [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). By installing it you can use the code you are using, once you `npm install mysql --save` and `require('mysql')` instead.

You seem to have a php background as all your comments indicate that. `mysqli` is a php extension and has nothing to do with node.js.

---

Sidenote:

A good indicator for which package to use or not to use are the github stars. If something that must be used by thousands of developers (like a mysql connector surely is) has only 1 star, that's a good indicator to keep on searching for another package.

Comment: That's another programming language. Use the mysql package in node.js instead @awesomeguy Make sure to read the docs, you can use parameterized queries and all that with it too

Comment: When I use the mysql package instead it says: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND % %:3306`

Comment: If you really used a `%` as a  host that's no wonder. @awesomeguy Use the host's address instead. localhost or the server's ip your mysql is running on

Comment: My MySQL server came with XAMPP and when I created a user in PHPMyAdmin it said that the host should be `%`. Using `localhost` will show a ACCESS DENIED error

Comment: I never worked with xampp, I don't know how to connect to a xampp server. The `%` is a wildcard character in mysql, and is used for `any` host, e.g. to give a user privileges from every host they try to connect. This is not the host you need. I'm sure there is plenty of information available on a google search. Before that, I'd try localhost as already commented

Comment: With some fiddling and searching, I managed to make it work, thanks for your help. Now I can use W3Schools to learn the stuff I need to.